# How can I update a Swing JTextField from a different class?

Tags: java, swing, scope, jtextfield

First of all I **have** searched this already. Has there been answers? Yes, but I can't seem to get anything working anyway. I have a very small amount of experience with Java so I don't know much.

Anyway, I have my main class called `Game` and I also have `GameFrame`

### `Game`

```
package xd.winkler.guessing_game;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

// main game class
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

// variables
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2723208685741428944L;

public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 480;
public final String TITLE = "Number Guessing Game";

private Thread thread;

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
Random r = new Random();
Boolean running = false, gameOver = false;
static int rounds = 0, tries = 0;;
static int userGuess = 0, randNum = 0;

// creates a new frame called GameFrame
public Game() {
    new GameFrame(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, this);
    System.out.println("[" + TITLE + " has started.]");
}

// called in the GameFrame class. starts the thread/game loop
public synchronized void start() {
    if (running)
        return;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}

// called at the end of the game loop. stops the program from running
public synchronized void stop() {
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    running = false;
    s.close();
}

// game loop
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        randNum = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        System.out.println("[Random Number: " + randNum + "]");
        this.gameOverCheck();
        System.out.println("Round: " + rounds);
        while (tries < 3) {
            tries++;
            this.guess();
        }
    }
    stop();
}

// checks if the game is over
public void gameOverCheck() {
    if (rounds == 10) {
        running = false;
    } else {
        rounds++;
    }
}

// gets the users guess and checks if it's right/wrong
public void guess() {
    userGuess = s.nextInt();
    if (userGuess == randNum) {
        System.out.println("RIGHT!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("WRONG!");
    }
}

// creates a new "Game" method to call/create the GameFrame
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game();
}
}
```

### `GameFrame`

```
package xd.winkler.guessing_game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class GameFrame extends Canvas {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7329745595446257624L;

static JButton enterButton;
public static JTextArea output;
public static JTextField input;
private static String ENTER = "Enter";
public static String testString = "test";
static JPanel panel;

public GameFrame(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, String TITLE, Game game) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // I did not do this section on my own and it's a mess
    // ---------------------------------------------------

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.setOpaque(true);

    ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
    output = new JTextArea(15, 50);
    output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    output.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(output);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
    inputpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    input = new JTextField(20);
    enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
    enterButton.setActionCommand(ENTER);
    enterButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    // enterButton.setEnabled(false);
    input.setActionCommand(ENTER);
    input.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) output.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    panel.add(scroller);
    inputpanel.add(input);
    inputpanel.add(enterButton);
    panel.add(inputpanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    frame.pack();

    // ---------------------------------------------------

    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    input.requestFocus();
    game.start();
}

public static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ev) {
        if (!input.getText().trim().equals("")) {
            String cmd = ev.getActionCommand();
            if (ENTER.equals(cmd)) {
                output.append(input.getText());
                if (input.getText().trim().equals(testString))
                    output.append(" = " + testString);
                else
                    output.append(" != " + testString);
                output.append("\n");
            }
        }
        input.setText("");
        input.requestFocus();
    }
}

}
```

As you can tell the game isn't nearly done. I'm just messing around and using system output to test things. I want to do all the main "game stuff" in the Game class and then output to the swing output text field I have. I also want to use the input box to set the `userGuess`.

I'm not sure how to use the different values throughout both classes and YES like I've said I have searched it up and looked and getters and setters but I don't really understand it. Also if you could recommend a good tutorial site or something to get good knowledge with Java that would be great.

Comment: *"Has there been answers? Yes, .."* Link the top 3. *"..but I can't seem to get anything working.."* Why not? Without knowing why the other answers did **not** work for you, how can we know how to answer differently?

Comment: You can't use GameFrame in Game if it is not inside Game's scope. You define a new GameFrame but never keep it in the Game's scope, so you can't ever tell GameFrame what to do.

Comment: General advice: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). An MCVE/SSCCE of this problem should not require threads, scroll-panes, altering the caret or scanners.. Simplify it down to the point there are just the two classes, one with the ability to print a value, the other with a text field. 2) And while I'm mentioning scanners, mixing the system input stream and GUIs will almost always end in tears. Change the code so the input is coming from GUI components.

Comment: *"Also if you could recommend a good tutorial site or something to get good knowledge with Java that would be great."* Asking for recommendations of off-site resources is off-topic for SO, but since it is not the main question, I'll respond to it in a comment. [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: @Lucas Your question is formed of several different questions. But I agree with Compass and Andrew. Your structure is the other way around and I would suggest to look up about getters and setters first. Just as a guide, what you need is a way of "setting" the value of the text in the "input" field you have, but from outside the class. Making the variable "public" is not the way to go.

Comment: This is commonly solved using a model-view-controller/observer pattern

Comment: @AndrewThompson The reason I'm mixing scanners and whatever else is because I was using it to test through the console since the GUI wasn't finished. It would be removed later.

Comment: @skw Alright, I'll try to look into getters and setters more. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Honestly was making a simple brick breaker game prior to this. The base of it made off of a tutorial (mostly the game loop). So I decided to try to use some of that for this which probably really wasn't needed but I'm new and I was trying whatever I could. I'm definitely going to re-write this all.